# Serverless lambda can´t send SMS, is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-sns

I Have a lambda running on serverless framework but when I try to send SMS by sns:Publish say this

```
INFO Error 
[AuthorizationError]: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/AWS-dev-us-east-1-
lambdaRole/AWS-dev-lambda is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: 
+57757575575 because no identity-based policy allows the SNS:Publish action at 
Request.extractError (/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-
sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29) at Request.callListeners 
(/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) at
 Request.emit (/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-
sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10) at Request.emit 
(/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14) at 
Request.transition (/var/task/src/optimoroutePoller/node_modules/aws-
sdk/lib/request.js:22:10) at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo 
(/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12) at 
/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10 at Request.
<anonymous> (/var/task/src/optimoroutePoller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9) at 
Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-
sdk/lib/request.js:685:12) at Request.callListeners 
(/var/task/src/lambda/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) { 
code: 'AuthorizationError', time: 2021-12-02T14:14:34.762Z, requestId: 'X', statusCode: 403, retryable: false, retryDelay: 69.252478880571 }
```

I tried to add the policy on serverless.yml

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Resource: 
        - arn:aws:sns:*:*:*        
      Action:
        - SNS:Publish
```

and don´t work
I tried to search the role on AWS roles and try to added but I can´t find the name of the role, I find of others lambdas, but I don´t know what exacly is, event I tried to permision on all that have serverless and it didn´t work

The wear is when I tried to send the SMS local, it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you compare your error message and the policy you have provided, you can see that the error mentioned the *resource* `+5...` while your policy mentions resources `arn:aws:sns:...`. If you switch your IAM policy to contain `Resource: '*'`, you should no longer receive permissions errors.

Comment: i try "Resource": "*" but it not work